# Does it make sense to combine select2 dropdowns with regular select dropdowns on a single form?

Tags: usability, dropdown, drop-down-list, select

I have a form that has a number of select dropdown boxes.  Some of them have large number of items (200+) so I have converted them to using the jquery select2 plugin which works great as you can search inline.

The issue is that some of the dropdowns only have a few items (10-20) so I kept as regular select drop downs (as I don't need the advanced features) but it now looks odd that half the form has the jquery select2 style and half don't.  This is the visual difference:

[image]

So my question is:

should i convert all of the items to select2 dropdown so there is a uniform style on the form even for one that don't really required the functionality just so the page is uniform

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you heard of the consistency heuristic?

Answer (score 3):

It will look better if they are consistent, however you shouldn't have functionality you don't need.

Have you tried using css to style the select so that it just *looks* like the select2?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you've figured this out by now but for anyone who finds this later - I would definitely go with the uniform style.

In Select2 you don't have to display the search.  You can use the `minimumResultsForSearch`property in your initialization.

So it would look like:

```
$('select').select2({
  //options
  minimumResultsForSearch: 20
});
```

Then it would only show search if there are 20 options or more.  Alternatively you can set it to a negative number (i.e. `-1`) to disable it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Watching the same controls, users expect the same functionality, but this will be wrong in your case.

This could lead to strange behavior, like re-opening drop-down list again having in mind: " The first time it didn't worked, maybe re-opening helps".

So your decision is more close to visual consistency, but form follows the function, so functional consistency is better for me.

Comment: I don't understand your answer.  Are you suggesting make all select2 or have a combination?

Comment: @leora, sorry for non-clarity, differentiating according to functionality is better, so try a combination.